# Slice strings in Go templates

Tags: go

How can I slice strings in a template using the `text/template` package? Of course, something like `{{ $myString[0:5] }}` is not working.

Comment: I am not sure you can. That said.. do you really want to? It would be much better if the slicing operation happened in code rather than the template.

Comment: I'm using a pre-built go package, so I cannot write my custom function without building the package myself. And I don't wanna do that.

Answer (score 9):

Define your own slicing function with [`template.Funcs`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs).

Code:

```
t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "stringSlice": func(s string, i, j int) string {
        return s[i:j]
    }
})
```

Template:

```
{{ stringSlice .MyString 0 5 }}
```

See also: [Template and custom function; panic: function not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843311/template-and-custom-function-panic-function-not-defined)

PS: As @dyoo correctly noted in the comments; this minimal  `stringSlice` function does nothing to prevent you from slicing UTF-8 characters in half. You should probably handle that in a live environment.

Comment: But do this in a way that's respectful of runes.  The above code is going to be mean to utf-8 encoded content.

Comment: Yes, it is a minimal example and it does not handle UTF-8. I'll note that in the answer.